# handwriting text recognition (CNN + LSTM + CTC) RNN explanation required

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, handwriting

I am trying to understand the following code, which is in python & tensorflow. Im trying to implement a handwriting text recognition. I am referring to the following code [here](https://github.com/githubharald/SimpleHTR/blob/master/src/Model.py)

I dont understand why the RNN output is put through a "atrous_conv2d"

This is the architecture of my model, takes a CNN input and pass into this RNN process and then pass it to a CTC.

```
 def build_RNN(self, rnnIn4d):

    rnnIn3d = tf.squeeze(rnnIn4d, axis=[2])  # squeeze remove 1 dimensions, here it removes the 2nd index

    n_hidden = 256
    n_layers = 2
    cells = []

    for _ in range(n_layers):
        cells.append(tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=n_hidden))

    stacked = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(cells)  # combine the 2 LSTMCell created

    # BxTxF -> BxTx2H
    ((fw, bw), _) = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw=stacked, cell_bw=stacked, inputs=rnnIn3d,
                                                    dtype=rnnIn3d.dtype)

    # BxTxH + BxTxH -> BxTx2H -> BxTx1X2H
    concat = tf.expand_dims(tf.concat([fw, bw], 2), 2)

    # project output to chars (including blank): BxTx1x2H -> BxTx1xC -> BxTxC
    kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1, 1, n_hidden * 2, len(self.char_list) + 1], stddev=0.1))
    rnn = tf.nn.atrous_conv2d(value=concat, filters=kernel, rate=1, padding='SAME')

    return tf.squeeze(rnn, axis=[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

The input to CTC loss layer will be of the form B x T x C

B - Batch Size
T - Max length of the output (twice max word length due to blank char)
C - number of character + 1 (blank char)

Input to atrous is of shape (B x T x 1 X 2T) == (batch, height ,width ,channel)
filter we are using is (1,1,2T,C) == (height ,width ,input channel ,output channel)

After atrous CNN we will get (B ,T ,1 ,C) which is the desired output for CTC

note: we will take a transpose before we input our image to CNN since tf is row major.

atrous with rate 1 is same as normal conv layer.

Comment: As CTC requires (B ,T ,C) as the input format, what is an alternative for 'atrous_conv2d' ? since RNN output is (B x T x 1 X 2T), how can i transform this to (B ,T ,C) ?

Comment: out from the function should be (B, T, 1, C) and you can use squeeze() to get (B, T , C). any Conv layer with padding ="SAME" and C number of filters will work.